# windows 10: force all windows to show up on taskbar

Tags: windows-10, accessibility

Taskbar seems to be selective to which windows it will show on the taskbar, for example, if you open a device property from device manager, it will not show the window on the taskbar at all.

Is there any setting to force all windows to appear on the taskbar?

Comment: Device Manager is not really an app (the way I think of an app) . If you close Device Manager all device manager dialogue windows must close making it very inconvenient to have them in the Task Bar.  All other regular apps I know of will end up in the Task Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Developers who create programs can alter how their window is managed by Windows. What kind of window is a window, is it always-on-top, does it show up in the taskbar, etc..?

This is a setting that is being set on or off at compile time, and can be altered externally by other programs. I have a program (paid) called Actual Tools Window Manager, which can force programs to show up in the taskbar (or hide).

Now, you would say, great! I'll use this and put it in the taskbar, right! Well.. You would not believe how many windows you have. When you right-click to open a context menu, this is also a window. Some programs have hidden windows that are on the screen, just hidden away from plain sight (plugins for music programs for example). A music project could easily have 20 plugins, creating 20 instances on your taskbar for each plugin.

Then there comes another problem... when a programmer doesn't expect a window to show up in the taskbar, it is possible the window does not even have a titlebar. You would get an empty button in your taskbar.

I have rules to make some windows semi transparent, and when I set it to everything, I started to see ghost windows. For example AMD Catalyst Control Panel has a hidden window on the desktop to manage context menu. By controlling all windows, I got weird effects, causing me to create specific rules to exclude most windows and only target those I really want.

Some programs have toolbars that can be undocked. This is also a window.

You catch my drift... There are far more windows than you realize, you would end up with a taskbar full of windows of which some will not even show anything if you click them, many won't have a caption, some are for plugins used by a program (chrome extension for example).

Oh, and I forgot the most important thing: because programmers don't expect a window to get focus that has not properly loaded (this will happen if you click a taskbar button from a form that is in hidden state), it may crash severely. If this is a form as part of a chrome plugin, it would crash your entire chrome.

So TL;DR: this is something you really don't want, or you have to target specific apps. In any case, you will have to get software that does this for you.